# error installing argon2 using npm install in node js (node-gyp) error

Tags: python, python-3.x, npm, python-2.x, node-gyp

I tried to install argon 2 on node js using `npm install argon2 --save`.
I think there is a problem with python (not sure why) or with node-gyp.

```
PS C:\angular\backend> npm install argon2 --save

> argon2@0.21.0 install C:\angular\backend\node_modules\argon2
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\angular\backend\node_modules\argon2>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\matan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\matan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\matan\Anaconda3\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\matan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\angular\backend\node_modules\argon2
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\angular\backend\package.json'
npm WARN backend No description
npm WARN backend No repository field.
npm WARN backend No README data
npm WARN backend No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! argon2@0.21.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the argon2@0.21.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\matan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-30T13_02_07_305Z-debug.log
PS C:\angular\backend>
```

expected argon2 to be installed to later be used for hashing.

Comment: Any progress on this issue?  Did you try to run with Python2.x?

Comment: i don't want to install python 2 on my machine because i use python 3 for other purposes. i don't want my computer to be messed by several versions of python

Answer (score 0):

From your anaconda path it looks like you were using Python 3.

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\matan\Anaconda3\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That would explain the syntax error at the print statement since it is not a print function. Try installing python2, or if you already have it installed, make sure it is on the path before python3.

Answer (score 0):

its so simple to handle this error 
if you follow my step you can resolve all error in gyp in nodejs 
in windows os .

STEP1 : goto this link

find and download and install build tools for visual studio 2019
  download and install it , and check nodejs tick , and restart your pc.

STEP2: install python 2.7 and sure that itis in your path , and u can access that with python (not python2)

STEP 3 : install this package fom npm 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools
make sure using powershell

then can install argon2 or any package you want 
:)